# Firefox web developer toolbar icons&text location

Tags: firefox

How can I make the text to be on the right of icons (where it was by default)?

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

I've been working with half-sized Firefox windows, and it seems that after that text has been moved to the bottom of the icons.

Comment: I believe that it is scaling automatically based on the screen size and we can not assign default value to it

Comment: well but it's stuck to some value somewhere , when I was using half size pinned to left window, now I use full size

Comment: What version of Firefox are (or were) you using?

Comment: I've been using 47th, and it seems that it was some conflict between FF and Classic Theme Restore addon. Just updated to 48 and it seems to be fixed now.